# Building Spring MVC application, Controller "Cannot find symbol" Model

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I first built my Spring MVC project with `gradle bootRun` with the following controller class successfully:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String hello() {
    return "resultPage";
  }
}
```

Then I changed it to pass data to my view class:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String hello(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello from the controller");
    return "resultPage";
  }
}
```

When I build my project now, I get the following error:

```
HelloController.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    public String hello(Model model) {
                        ^
  symbol:   class Model
  location: class HelloController
1 error
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: maybe a missing import?

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga Yes, correct! I just added an answer a few mins ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

If we want the DispatcherServlet to inject the Model into the function, one of the things we should do is import the Model class.

```
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
```

So, I changed my controller class to the following and it worked!

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String hello(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello from the controller");
    return "resultPage";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ModelAndView API:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView hello() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("resultPage");
    modelAndView.addObject("message", "Hello from the controller");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

ModelAndView docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html

Comment: Why the author must use it? It fixes the problem?